# xcode 4.4.1+: message sent do deallocated instance - not occurring in 4.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode

I have an older app that does not use ARC. When trying to address a rather simple change, I got stuck on an annoying problem:

When running this:

```
NSMutableArray *arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
NSLog(@"arr=%08lx", (unsigned long)arr);
[arr release];
```

I get this in console:

```
arr=06a2ca50
*** -[__NSArrayM class]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6a2ca50
```

The error comes immediately after single stepping over the release statement.

As I don't recall seeing this before upgrading to 4.4.1, is there anything new in xcode 4.4.1 that explains the above?

Or am I just overseeing something very obvious in the above code?

**Update:** after downgrading to 4.3.3 the problem disappeared. Currently looking for what might be causing this. I couldn't reproduce with a new/clean project. 
Same problem with xcode 45-DP4 / iOS6..

Comment: I'm about to file a radar report to Apple on this. Meanwhile stripped the project to an absolute minimum and tested on two different machines with xcode 4.3.3 (ok), 4.4.1 (problem) and 4.5-dp4 (problem). What is interesting is that the message only appears when the app is stopped in the debugger. An [NSAutoreleasePool showPools] does not list the object (which is the correct behavior).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project file had NSZombieEnabled=YES in the environment variables of the debug scheme.

I'm not sure why this warning occurs under 4.4.1+ with NSZombieEnabled=YES since none of the standard analyze and diagnostic tools report memory issues.

If anyone has more insight as to why this warning occurs on 4.1.1+, I'm eager to learn. In general I'm keen in taking a compiler or debug warning serious and don't see disabling them as the best option..

Comment: I'm using 4.4.1 and all the zombie and memory tools seem to stop producing the log messages they were in the past